# Український відповідник Sleepwalker (рос. Лунатик)?

Tags: переклад, from-english, запозичені-слова

Чи є український відповідник Sleepwalker? 
Пропонований гуглом Лунатик наврядчи є українським зважаючи на похідну Луну (місяць).
Другий варіант - Сомнамбуліст - скоріше медичний термін.
Здається, мусить бути давніше народне поняття, якщо їх не вважали просто зачарованими і т.п.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

На додачу до "**сновиди**", словник [r2u.org.ua](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) додає ще:

- сновія
- снохода

і цитує вірш Г. Чупринки "Снохода":

> Все я знаю... Все забула...
>   Я **снохода**, я **сновія**,
>   Вся в уяві потонула,
>   Я легенька, наче мрія.

Снохода є також у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/snokhoda):

> **СНОХО́ДА**, и, чол. і жін., рідко. Те саме, що лунатик.  * У порівняннях. *Сам не стямився [Михайлик], як замугикав стиха та й подався, мов той снохода, вниз до міста, шляху не вибираючи (ільч., Козацьк. роду.., 1958, 338).*

Ще згадуються "місячник" і "місячниця", але у СУМі є лише [декілька інших](http://sum.in.ua/s/misjachnyk) значень (наприклад "заходи які проводяться протягом місяця", або "періодичне видання що виходить щомісяця").

Ще у обговоренні тлумачного словника на [r2u](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=5114) є "**сноброда**". Пошук у Google Books дав [три згадування цього слова](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82&num=100&lr=lang_uk&tbm=bks&gws_rd=cr&ei=uwAjWdLRF8bYmwHyxavIBw#lr=lang_uk&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&tbm=bks&q=%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0):

- у "Практичному словнику синонімів української мови" виданого у 1993;
- у романі В'ячеслава Сахно "Циркулятор", виданого у 2008 році ("Якось я читав, що в Португалії навіть корова-сноброда об'явилась");
- та у "Віснику Прикарпатського університету", де це слово включили у список "недоречних архаїзмів" у перекладі англійської книги.

Answer (score 18):

Згідно із СУМ це [сновида](http://sum.in.ua/s/snovyda):

> СНОВИ́ДА, и, чол. і жін. Те саме, що лунатик

або ж [лунатик](http://sum.in.ua/s/lunatyk)

> ЛУНА́ТИК, а, чол. Хворий на лунатизм.

До речі, це слово не є беззаперечним русизмом, бо початково походить від латинського lunaticus (божевільний), яке як позначення цієї хвороби є застарілим і було згодом замінене сомнамбулізмом

Comment: Також зустрічав "сновида", але r2u.org.ua підказує що є ще варіанти "сновія", "снохода": "Я снохо́да, я снові́я, вся в уя́ві потону́ла" (["Снохода"](https://www.pysar.net/virsz.php?poet_id=81&virsz_id=105) Г. Чупринка, 1910).

Answer (score 1):

У словнику Б.Грінченка --  [*Сновида*](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/55371-snovyda.html#show_point)

Comment: -1: Ця відповідь не пояснює значення і можливих відтінків. Пояснення «Лунатикъ» несе мало інформації, враховуючи, що запитання про переклад з англійської, а російський варіант там для уточнення. Взагалі, StackExchange не заохочує відповіді в один рядок. Окрім того, ця відповідь не несе нічого нового, порівняно з наявними відповідями. Порівняйте якість наявних відповідей і цієї.